# "Unable to unzip" drush make error

Tags: xampp, mime-types, drush

I have been puzzling over an "unable to unzip" error I am receiving when drushing a make file. What's weird is that tar.gz files are being extracted without errors.

I use XAMPP 1.8.0, with PHP 5.4.4, on Windows 7 and the make file is being run from within xampp/htdocs/mysite. I've run this make file many times without error on our linux dedicated server, but I am running this now on my own laptop.

I'm no expert on mime types, but the error seems to be relating to that. The code from the command prompt is below. Any help with this would be very much appreciated! Thanks.

```
https---github.com-downloads-tinymce-tinymce-tinymce_3.4.7.zip          [notice]

retrieved from cache. [121.66 sec, 6.23 MB]
tinymce downloaded from                                                     [ok]

https://github.com/downloads/tinymce/tinymce/tinymce_3.4.7.zip.
[121.68 sec, 6.23 MB]
No fileinfo or mime_magic support available. [121.68 sec, 6.23 MB]       [debug]

Examining                                                                [debug]

C:\\\\Users\\\\myname\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp/make_tmp_1347382411_504f6c8bb8c5
2/tinymce_3.4.7.zip
headers. [121.68 sec, 6.23 MB]
Mime type for                                                           [notice]

C:\\\\Users\\\\myname\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp/make_tmp_1347382411_504f6c8bb8c5
2/tinymce_3.4.7.zip
is application/zip [121.68 sec, 6.23 MB]
No fileinfo or mime_magic support available. [121.68 sec, 6.23 MB]       [debug]

Examining                                                                [debug]

C:\\\\Users\\\\myname\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp/make_tmp_1347382411_504f6c8bb8c5
2/tinymce_3.4.7.zip
headers. [121.68 sec, 6.23 MB]
Mime type for                                                           [notice]

C:\\\\Users\\\\myname\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp/make_tmp_1347382411_504f6c8bb8c5
2/tinymce_3.4.7.zip
is application/zip [121.68 sec, 6.23 MB]
Unable to unzip
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to install "unzip" package (I know, you're using XAMPP, but there should be a solution on how to do it somewhere).
At least Linux `sudo apt-get install unzip` solved mine issues.  :)